# Why is a pristine form always valid in angular

Tags: angular, angular6

I have this code:

```
<form #userForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save(userForm)">
    <input type="email" #contactEmail="ngModel" email minlength="2"  [(ngModel)]="contactInformation.email" class="form-control" id="contactEmail" name="contactEmail" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
    <div *ngIf="contactEmail.invalid">
      Please input a valid email
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
</form>
```

When this code is loaded contactEmail is set to valid and pristine, and the error message is not shown. What I want is the following two to be true:

1. If the form is loaded with a "" value for email, the error should be shown.
2. If the form is loaded with "valid@email.com" for email, the error should not be shown.

How do I do this?

EDIT: I've gotten 2 answers, none of witch work as expected, here is a stackBlitz that demo's this:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wwttsr

Expected behavior is that the error message is shown on load, and the placeholder is filled out.

Comment: tried `updateValueAndValidity` on form load of any control which re-evaluates ?

Comment: I have not tried that, can you give some example code on how I would do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my code had a very subtle bug. Email and minLenght validation DOES NOT SET required. So simply setting required also fixes everything.

```
<form #userForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save(userForm)">
    <input type="email" #contactEmail="ngModel" email minlength="2" required [(ngModel)]="contactInformation.email" class="form-control" id="contactEmail" name="contactEmail" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
    <div *ngIf="contactEmail.invalid">
      Please input a valid email
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try to add `contactInformation.email = ""` in your ts - this will make your value as empty string - whereas form validation will take place if the value is not `null` don't bind `null` to the value at initial load

Hope this will solve your problem  - Happy coding !!

**Update**

I have done some changes on your `*ngIf` condition that hold your placeholder on the `input` text

```
<form #f="ngForm">
    <input type="text" minlength="10" [(ngModel)]="coumnNameModel" name="coumnName" #coumnName="ngModel" email placeholder="please write">
</form>
<small *ngIf="coumnNameModel != null && coumnNameModel.length <= 10">
    Field needs 10 characters
</small>
<small *ngIf="coumnName.invalid && coumnNameModel.length > 10">
    Enter a valid email 
</small>
<button (click)="setRequired()">Set field as required</button>
```

Declare your `coumnNameModel` as `coumnNameModel = ""` just empty string and read the length of the string to show the error message - **I have added couple of validation which checks both for initial load and if the input is `valid` or not**

Please check and let me know if it doesn't work - this makes your placeholder intact on initial load

Hope this will work i have checked form you source

Comment: This had no effect, but if I set it to ' ' (space) it works

Comment: For textarea with minLength set, this however breaks the placeholder functionality

Comment: Yep in case of `<textarea>` you can use as null to retain the placeholder - it will bind the empty string on the `input` and you can't expect to get a placeholder in this case - if in case if you want your error to be loaded on the initial load you can use this method

Comment: so I can't have both a placeholder and a validation message?

Comment: I've added a stackblitz where you can se that this does not work as you are describing.

Comment: Yeah - if you bind empty string placeholder will not be in the place - that removes your validation - I will check the code and let you know if there is any scenario

Comment: Your answer does not use validation: (coumnNameModel != null && coumnNameModel.length < 10) is just an IF check not validation.

Comment: Yep that will act as a initial validator - if the user enters more than ten chars your email validator will run - incase of having placeholder in place of initial load i felt this was a solution :)  i have used `OR` operator too that creates validation for both :) Thanks

Comment: No, it will not ACT AS A INITIAL validation. That code is BAD and DANGEROUS and should not be used. Ever. What it does is trick you into believing that your validation works, when it does NOT WORK!

Comment: I willl check give me time - will check once I'm back to offf :)

Comment: Yep as you mentioned there was some changes in the code - sorry for the confusion - now i have updated the new code please check the updated answer :)

Comment: Still not validation, still dangerous

Comment: Yep that feels like a work around not a solution - you want your placeholder in place so that made me to add validation in this method :) No problem thanks - required will work the same way either the property is null or empty :)